# В каких случаях нужно регистрировать стили(WordPress)

Tags: css, wordpress

Я нашел два варианта подключения CSS стилей в WordPress,
они оба работают почти одинаково.
Но в первом варианте идет регистрация стиля, а во втором варианте регистрации нет.

Отсюда у меня возник вопрос:
**Зачем вообще регистрировать стили, если и без регистрации все работает?**

**1-Вариант с регистрацией стилей:**

```js
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Join_CSS' );

function Join_CSS() {
wp_register_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'styles');
}
?>
```

**2-Вариант без регистрации:**

```js
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Join_CSS' );

function Join_CSS() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css',
[], '1.0', 'all');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В простых случаях достаточно enqueue.

Регистрация нужна, когда есть зависимости и относительно сложный код принятия решения, какие стили/скрипты надо запускать. В этом случае при выполнении wp_enqueue_style будут автоматически запущены все зависимые зарегистрированные стили.

То же самое относится и к скриптам.

Comment: Например, если буду делать пагинацию, где будет использоваться js-код, то нужно будет регистрировать этот самый js-код?

Comment: Я не уверен, что правильно оформил свой 1-ый вариант с регистрацией =( Посмотрите пожалуйста, нет ли в моём 1-варианте ошибок.